# Google Map API V3: MarkerClusterer won't break down into markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an application where I'm using the Google Map API to display markers for posts made by users using their lat/lon. I employed the MarkerClusterer capability for better organization of the markers, which works but with a bug of sorts.

Essentially, I've been testing this at home so the lat/lon has been the same for all test posts. Before using MarkerClusterer, zooming far into the map would eventually reveal all the markers. Unfortunately, using the MarkerClusterer, if there is, for example, a "5" listed for the number of markers that are very close together such as these test posts, clicking on the cluster reveals nothing. No markers ever appear when these are very close together. To reiterate, these markers do appear without the MarkerClusterer.

I upgraded to MarkerClustererPlus v2.0.9 per another post that described other issues with the MarkerClusterer but that hasn't solved the problem.

Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: geocodezip suggested the overlappingmarkerspidifier, which sounds great, but my code is fairly involved and I'm not sure how to incorporate it. Any insight much appreciated. Code follows:

```
function mainGeo()
{
     if (navigator.geolocation) 
        {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( mainMap, error, {maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true} );
    }
    else
    {
          alert("Sorry, but it looks like your browser does not support geolocation.");
    }
}


var stories = {{storyJson|safe}};
var geocoder;
var map;
var markers = [];

function loadMarkers(stories){

    for (i=0;i<stories.length;i++) {
        var story = stories[i];    
        if (story.copy.length > 120) {
                story.copy = story.copy.substring(0, 120) + "...";
            }

        (function(story) {      
            var pinColor = "69f2ff";
                var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=S|" + pinColor,
                    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story.latitude, story.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map, icon: pinImage});
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div >'+
                '<div >'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h2 class="firstHeading">'+story.headline+'</h2>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<span>'+story.author+'</span><br />'+
                '<span>'+story.city+'</span><br />'+
                '<span>'+story.topic+'</span><br />'+
                '<p>'+story.date+'</p>'+
                '<p>'+story.copy+'</p>'+
                '<p><a href='+story.url+'>Click to read story</a></p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'

          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,this);

          });
            markers.push(marker);

        })(story);

    }

}




 function mainMap(position)
 {
       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       // Define the coordinates as a Google Maps LatLng Object
       var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
       var width = window.innerWidth - 80;
       size = width;

       // Prepare the map options
       var mapOptions =
      {
                  zoom: 15,
                  center: coords,
                  mapTypeControl: false,
                  navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // Create the map, and place it in the map_canvas div
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        // Place the initial marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: coords,
                  map: map,
                  title: "Your current location!"
        });

        loadMarkers(stories);
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

    }


  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }


function error() {
    alert("You have refused to display your location. You will not be able to submit stories.");
    }

mainGeo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this [post in the v3 group: Overlapping markers on your Google Map? Meet OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/f53eb613af7dbec0#) might help:

Sounds like the [OverlapingMarkerSpiderifier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) solves your problem.

Comment: This sounds great. Thanks. Incorporating it will be the problem as I already have an involved setup and my JS is dubious at best. :)

Comment: If you have data that would show it working (with lots of overlapping markers) and can post that, or a link to your map that shows the problem you are trying to solve, perhaps someone might be able to make an example that shows how the spiderifier handles that.