# Marker cluster displaying only one Marker when having exact corodinates

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6wp7enot/12/

```
var map = null;
var markerArray = []; //create a global array to store markers
var myPoints = [
    [43.65654, -79.90138, 'ABC'],
    [43.65654, -79.90138, 'DEF'],
    [43.65654, -79.90138, 'GHA']
]; //create global array to store points

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787, -79.359741),
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var mcOptions = {
        gridSize: 50,
        maxZoom: 15
    };
    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
    });


    for (var i = 0; i < myPoints.length; i++) {
        createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(myPoints[i][0], myPoints[i][1]), myPoints[i][2]);
    }

    mc.addMarkers(markerArray, true);
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

function createMarker(latlng, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
    });


    markerArray.push(marker); //push local var marker into global array
}

window.onload = initialize;
```

Could you please let me know how to handle this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map API V3: MarkerClusterer won't break down into markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213030/google-map-api-v3-markerclusterer-wont-break-down-into-markers)

Answer (score 0):

You created all the three markers at same position means same latitude and longitude. So three markers created at one place only. Please change latitude and longitude of other two elements from the array.
eg. 
`var myPoints = [
    [43.65654, -79.90138, 'ABC'],
    [44.65654, -79.90138, 'DEF'],
    [45.65654, -79.90138, 'GHA']
]; //create global array to store points`